# ASP.NET requested page in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I want to be able to globally grab a reference to the `Page` object that is currently being requested, so I've added a Global.asax file.

Is there any way to do this? I assume it has something to do with the `Application_BeginRequest` event.

Comment: why? there has to be a better way in what you are trying to do

Comment: And what do you want to do with such a reference?

Comment: At any given page request, I need a handle to the current page to be stored in a static class. This class uses the page reference to do some server-side IO.

Comment: Can't you simply subclass from `Page` that does what you want and use the subclass as the base type for all you pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that is a subclass of `Page` that does what you want and use this subclass as the base type for all you pages.

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
 //... override whatever you want, add functionality, whatever
}
```

All other pages:

```
public class Index : MyPage
{
   // Automatically get new behaviour
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can access the current handler (the page) from global.asax, but not from any [stage of the request life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). I.e. it is not possible in BeginRequest, but it is possible during PreRequestHandlerExecute:

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var page = (Context.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page);
}
```

Note that page might still be null, if the handler is not a page. Also, I'm not sure your approach is the correct one. Maybe you should explain in more detail what you want to attempt?

Comment: Yeah, Oded's suggestion seems like it's going to work out better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use http module to catch the every request for each page on your application and do whatever you want with the request.

Comment: You can catch the request at any stage of the request life cycle using the http module.

Answer (score 1):

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page
if(page != null) /// do something with page
```

PreRequestHandlerExecute should be fine for your purposes (if you don't fancy writing your own HttpModule, which is in fact very easy)

Comment: The Current Handler appears to be null at this point in the request lifecycle.

Comment: try PreRequestHandlerExecute as MAN suggests